# Returning nil from addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: block doesn't suppress events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

The following code doesn't suppress mouse drags in my app:

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
   return (NSEvent *)nil;
}];
```

I'm still able to drag UI elements inside the app. As far as I know, if you return `nil` inside the block, the event won't be dispatched to the app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "drag UI elements", but I suspect that this note in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW17):

> Your handler will not be called for events that are consumed by nested event-tracking loops such as control tracking, menu tracking, or window dragging...

is the explanation. Various `NSResponder` subclasses, such as buttons when they get clicked, enter a ["private tracking loop"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW4) where they grab all events until they receive one in particular which ends the loop.

You should put a log statement inside that block and make sure that you're actually getting an event passed in when you expect to.

Comment: Ah cool. That makes sense. By "drag UI elements" I meant I have a NSSlider on my window. So looks like when dragging the slider the event doesn't get passed in.

Comment: Yup. Pretty sure `NSSlider` does the tracking loop thing. I think you'll have to subclass if you really need to grab those events. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812367/nsbutton-subclass-that-responds-to-right-clicks/ might be helpful...