# Recognize if nsbutton is pressed with a right mouse button swift

Tags: swift, right-click, nsbutton

I have many NSButtons made programmatically and I need to recognize, if one of the buttons is pressed with right mouse button. Is there any way to do it in swift?

Code of creating buttons:

```
var height = 0
var width = 0

var ar : Array<NSButton> = []

var storage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

height = storage.integerForKey("mwHeight")
width = storage.integerForKey("mwWidth")

var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var k = 1
    for i in 1...height {
        for j in 1...width {
            var but = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: x, y: y + 78, width: 30, height: 30))
            but.tag = k
            but.title = ""
            but.action = Selector("buttonPressed:")
            but.target = self
            but.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle(rawValue: 6)!
            ar.append(but)
            self.view.addSubview(but)
            x += 30
            k++
        }
        y += 30
        x = 0
    }
```

Comment: try`override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {println("button clicked")}` got the example from [https://github.com/twe4ked/modal-menu/blob/master/ModalMenu/StatusItemView.swift]

Comment: @chirag90, page not found

Comment: Moreover, I need to know which of my buttons was clicked

Comment: https://github.com/twe4ked/modal-menu/blob/master/ModalMenu/StatusItemView.swift

Comment: @chirag90, but how to know which of buttons was pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSButton subclass that responds to right clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812367/nsbutton-subclass-that-responds-to-right-clicks)

Comment: @RehcsifMit I don't think so, there's the biggest part written on obj-c, and the part written on swift doesn't answer my question

Comment: OK... it's pretty easy to port it to Swift, and even easier to include it as an Obj-C file in your otherwise Swift project.  But glad you found an alternate solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. You can add `NSClickGestureRecognizer` to each of buttons with this code:

```
var x = 0
    var y = 0
    k = 1
    for i in 1...height {
        for j in 1...width {
            var but = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: x, y: y + 78, width: 30, height: 30))
            but.tag = k
            but.title = ""
            but.action = Selector("buttonPressed:")
            but.target = self
            but.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle(rawValue: 6)!

            var ges = NSClickGestureRecognizer()
            ges.target = self
            ges.buttonMask = 0x2 //for right mouse button
            ges.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
            ges.action = Selector("rightClick:")
            but.addGestureRecognizer(ges)

            ar.append(but)
            self.view.addSubview(but)
            x += 30
            k++
        }
        y += 30
        x = 0
    }
```

And in function `rightClick` you can access the button the following way:

```
func rightClick(sender : NSGestureRecognizer) {
    if let but = sender.view as? NSButton {
        // access the button here
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I make it work for Control Click(Which is equivalent to right click) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'buttonPressed' function will be called with the NSButton that was pressed.

```
func buttonPressed(b:NSButton) {
    debugPrintln(b.tag)
}
```

That code will print out the button tag you have specified when you made the button.

Comment: this function will only be called if user pressed the `NSButton` with left mouse button